# compilation on cygwin64 doesn't work with g++ 4.9.2

Tags: cygwin, compile, make, g++

I have

- GNU make version 4.0
- g++/gcc version 4.9.2

Command `make clean` works perfectly

But when I use command `make` to compile

I got this error

```
C:/cygwin64/lib/gcc/x86_64-pc-cygwin/4.9.2/cc1plus.exe: error while loading shared libraries: cygisl-10.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'prog' failed
make: *** [prog] Error 1
```

What did I do wrong? Did I miss something?

Comment: I have exactly the same compilation problem (it has nothing to do with make - it is problem with compiler dependencies). See my post:
http://tinyurl.com/opy5tlx

Comment: I think I agree with you about the compilation and not make. on my univ computer, they have version 4.9.0 and it's all fine. on my laptop with cygwin, I can only get 4.9.2 or 4.9.3 or 5.2.0

Answer (score 2):

That dependency is in the libisl10 package.  Resolve the dependency by installing the libisl10 package, using the cygwin setup.exe software installer.

Comment: So, how does one resolve the dependency?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it more complete.

Answer (score 2):

I've just had this problem on a fresh Cygwin64 install on Windows 10.

Run cygwin setup, setup-x86_64.exe or setup-x86.exe, search for libcloog, and libisl.

From the Libs category select:

```
libcloog-isl4
libisl10
```

This will pull in a few more dependencies, and after that GCC worked.

Comment: This duplicates another answer and adds no new content. Please don't post an answer unless you actually have something new to contribute.

Comment: Normally, I do not add more than a comment. The problem is current. libcloog is new information, and this addresses the comment last October by Scott for a more complete answer.

Comment: I installed libisl10, but no libcloog-isl4 can be found in the list in my cygwin 2.9.0 setup-x86_64.exe.

Comment: My solution was to install the cygwin package `gcc-g++` as well as `gcc-core` and `make`. I was tricked by the fact that g++ was found in the $PATH, but pointed to ActiveState Perl /cygdrive/c/Perl/site/bin/g++.